# TCP Client retrieving no data from the server

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to receive data from a TCP Server in python. I try to open a file at the server and after reading its content, try to send it to the TCP Client. The data is read correctly from the file as I try to print it first on the server side but nothing is received at the Client side.
PS. I am a beginner in network programming.

Server.py

```
import socket
import os
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("", 5000))
server_socket.listen(5)

client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
print ("Conencted to - ",address,"\n")
data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print ("Filename : ",data)
fp = open(data,'r')
string = fp.read()
fp.close()
print(string)
size = os.path.getsize(data)
size = str(size)
client_socket.send(size.encode())
client_socket.send(string.encode())
client_socket.close()
```

Client.py

```
import socket,os
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("", 5000))
size = 1024

print ("Your filename : \n")
string = input()
client_socket.send(string.encode())
size = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print ("The file size is - ",size[0:2]," bytes")
size = int(size[0:2])
string = client_socket.recv(size).decode()
print ("\nFile contains : ")
print (string)
client_socket.close();
```

Comment: What is your observation on running the client?

Comment: This is what i get at the client side :

Your filename : 

data.txt
The file size is -  25  bytes

File contains :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#Get just the two bytes indicating the content length - client_socket.send(size.encode())

buffer = client_socket.recv(2)
size = len(buffer) 
print size
print ("The file size is - ",buffer[0:2]," bytes")

#Now get the remaining. The actual content

print buffer.decode()
buffer = client_socket.recv(1024)
size = len(buffer)
print size
print buffer.decode()
```

Comment: stuck....it seems like server just keeps on sending while the client just keeps on receiving..

Comment: Do you have the while loop put in as per the other answer. Can you try with your original code?

Comment: Tried it without the loop, it prints the size as '0' bytes.

Comment: I have edited my post. I am doing two `recv`. Once just the first two bytes to get content length and then the actual content. Try if that helps.

Comment: Tried this as well no data is received :/

Comment: What are the prints on the server side? Does it print the file name sent by the client and content. The code worked for me for a valid file.

Comment: Yes, the server does print the name, it also prints the file contents but nothing is received at the client side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125503/discussion-between-prabhu-and-adil-r).

Answer (score 1):

Add Accept() in while loop as below.

> while True: 
>   client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
>   print ("Conencted to - ",address,"\n")
>   ......

Comment: How does this change help?

Comment: You have max connection allowed 5, so accept should be in loop.--it doesn't work for more than one connection without loop. If its still failing check what error its giving with try catch. try:
   client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
except socket.error:

Comment: still no exception, just stuck.